# Java -version prints a wrong version

Tags: java, ant

I have multiple versions of Java installed in the environment(I know it is bad). I've set the JAVA_HOME to `jdk 1_4` directory. This is not installed, but extracted from zip and placed it somewhere. We have `java 1.8 JRE` also installed in the system. I never set the path to this installed directory. Now i'm trying to run some ant script that depends on jdk 1_4. I get some exception saying that it is not able to find tools.jar in `java1.8...` .

My question is that when the path and java_home are set to jdk 14 why does the ant look for 1.8 version of java? I'm  confused.

**Update**: I have looked up the duplicate issue.

`Additional details:` Java -version prints 1.8 with jdk 14 in the path and java_home. I uninstalled 1.8. reopened cmd tried java -version, now it errors out saying that it is not able to find java1.8 instead of trying to find the next java available in the path or java_home.

Error shown:

```
C:\Users\usrpao>java
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

Comment: If you are on linux, try `which java`, the JAVA_HOME is override by that one I guess.

Comment: @DavidPostill I've looked at that post, it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: The Windows equivalent of what @flybird said is `where java`.

Comment: Since you are on win7 I guess, remove jdk8 & jre8 from control panel, remove the folder, reboot, then install java 8 again, this is just bad behavior of win7 & jdk8,

Answer (score 7):

> I have multiple versions of Java installed in the environment(I know it is bad). I've set the JAVA_HOME to jdk 1_4 directory.

Not wrong at all. I have a similar setup because I have to switch between Java version.

- First, install Java JDKs in the root of your drive. No spaces in the directory names. For example, `C:\Java\Java-1.6-21` and `C:\Java\Java-1.7-5`.
- In your Environment Variables section in your System Control Panel (under Advance), create an environment variable to point to each one of these Java Home directories. For example, `JAVA_HOME_17 = C:\Java\Java-1.7.5` and `JAVA_HOME_16 = C:\Java\Java-1.6-21`. This should be a System Environment variable.
- Create a JAVA_HOME environment variable that points to the Java version you want: `JAVA_HOME = %JAVA_HOME_17%`.
- Now in the System PATH, prefix the PATH (the very first entry) with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

When you open a console window, your default `java` and `javac` commands will be the correct Java version.

If you need to change a version, change the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the correct environment variable and open a new console window. Now that new Java will be in your path.

**NOTE**: It is vitally important that `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is in the first part of your `PATH` before `C:\Windows\System32`. You don't want the `java.exe` that exists in that directory to be your default java.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense now. will try on monday!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the operating system, so:

- on windows, java installs a java.exe in C:\Windows\system32, which is probably on the path before java_home, and so gets picked up
- on Linux, various distributions that support multiple installed java versions will also have some symlink earlier on the path. Run 'which java' to determine where that symlink is

Comment: Not when I do java -version it is still looking for java 1.8 path, reports that it is unable to find it.

Comment: Updated the post. Please check.

Comment: Please add the output of 'echo %PATH%'. Also, is there a java.exe in system32?

Comment: @Zeus That suggests that Java 1.8 is not installed correctly.  Was it deleted?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've uninstalled it after I got the issue. I see java.exe in the system32

Comment: So it wasn't properly removed. Maybe you have more versions installed?

Comment: Yup, more versions installed. I had to delete them from ssytem32 folder, it works now. I'm not sure if it causes any trouble. But the path has the java bin folder mapped

Comment: @Zeus - the question is what comes 1st on the path - system32 or java_home\bin ?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple java versions in the system is the problem, I uninstalled all the java versions first. Restarted my machine. Path and java home points to the jdk 1.4. `java -version` now points to the version specified in the `path`. Thanks all.